# Почему верстка ломается в IE?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, internet-explorer

Ну, как обычно, верстка везде смотрится нормально, кроме IE, причем даже в 11 версии. Вот пример одной из страниц http://silencer.website/suits/main_01.html. До этого такого не было, пока не начал использовать vh и vw. Есть способ как-то это исправить? Может полифил какой-нибудь( уже парочку подключал, но ничего не изменилось ). А может это вообще все из-за rem, т.к. там размеры текста и некоторых маленьких блоков или иконок в них. Вообщем уже не знаю что делать.

Скрин из IE:

[image: Скрин из IE]

Скрин из Chrome( как и должно быть ):

[image: Скрин из Chrome]

Comment: P.S. Щас вспомнил, может это не важно, но на всякий случай. Там брейкпоинты в медиа-запросах тоже в rem измеряются.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Comment: да вроде нормально , за исключением того что не прокручивается ни в хроме ни в EDGE

Comment: Максим Ленский, можно скрины? Прокручиваться и не должно)

Comment: Elena, смотрел уже там, оттуда и брал полифилы. Мне сейчас важнее то, была ли у кого-нибудь такая проблема и как ее решили.

Comment: здесь нельзя выкладывать скрины , это не форум ... ваш вопрос вообще следует закрыть , если я говор нормально это означает что ТАК И ЕСТЬ

Comment: Эм...смешно, откуда тогда я взял скрин, что все съехало?

Comment: И почему нельзя выкладывать скрины? Я должен же увидить результат, наслово я не верю.

Comment: @SilencerWeb, решается заменой на `html,body, .твой-блок {width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: Elena, не, там масштаб был слишком увеличен, как-то тестил svg, забыл вернуть масштаб обратно, т.к. этим трешем не пользуюсь. Но все равно спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Хм, проблема была в чересчур большом масштабе, как изменил до 100%, все стало отлично.

Comment: Задумайся об адаптивности.

Comment: лол, ты о чем ?

Comment: Адаптация сайта не только под разные девайсы а еще и под разные масштабы браузера.

Comment: Ну сложновато, знаешь ли. Не нарушить прихоти дизайна и адаптировать сайт под все разрешения, да еще и слайдовый

Comment: Ну это уже как хочешь :) Например ютуб вообще не адаптивный (как и поиск Google, как и Stack Owerflow). Так что можешь не париться, я пошутил.

Comment: Да я и не собирался)